# Flex items not shrinking when window gets smaller

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, plotly

I'm trying to fit two plotly plots next to each other inside a CSS flexbox. I want them to resize when the window is resized. It works as expected when the window grows, but the plots don't shrink when the window gets smaller.

```js
var trace1 = {};
var trace2 = {};

var plotdiv1 = document.getElementById("plotdiv1");
var plotdiv2 = document.getElementById("plotdiv2");

Plotly.newPlot(plotdiv1, [trace1]);
Plotly.newPlot(plotdiv2, [trace2]);

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  Plotly.Plots.resize(plotdiv1);
  Plotly.Plots.resize(plotdiv2);
});
```

```css
.plot-div {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.plot-col {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.my-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="my-container">
    <div class="plot-col">
      <div id="plotdiv1" class="plot-div"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="plot-col">
      <div id="plotdiv2" class="plot-div"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd0reepd/

I am probably misunderstanding how flexbox works, but if I replace the plots with images, they shrink as expected.

I have tried to debug this and found plotlys internal function `plotAutoSize`, which calls `window.getComputedStyle` and sets the plot size accordingly. I have used `console.log` to look at the return values of `window.getComputedStyle` and they get "stuck" at the largest size when the window shrinks.

How can I get the plots to shrink to fit the window and stay next to each other in the same row?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

An initial setting on flex items is `min-width: auto`. This means that a flex item cannot, by default, be smaller than its content.

You can override this setting with `min-width: 0` or `overflow` with any value other than `visible`. Add this to your code:

```
.plot-col {
    min-width: 0;
}
```

[Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd0reepd/1/)

More info: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

---

The reason for this setting is explained here: [w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)).

Comment: ...and thus ends 45 minutes of pounding my head on my desk.  thanks so much!

Comment: this is so important, they should write it on the fisrt line of the doc

Comment: For my case, this helped partially shrink my content but it didn't want to shrink all the way to fit the flex sizing. What did work was setting `width: 0;` instead of `min-width: 0;`.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on the container solved it for my case, so don't forget to also check out the suggested original question at the very top of the page (in the "duplicate" notice)

Comment: Fact is my table had the 'responsive-table' class which made me think it could not come from content size... but it did... Thanks a lot !

Comment: This also counts for min-height when working with `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: Oh man, you not just saved my day, also my job!