# angular chart.js not resizing (shinking) in a flexbox

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

See the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/m942h0wm/6/

HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app">
  <div class="main">
    <p>Main</p>
  </div>
  <div class="aside">
    <canvas class="chart chart-doughnut" 
        chart-data="[10,20,40]" 
        chart-labels="['one', 'two', 'three']">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  border: solid 10px;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

.aside {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

if you shrink the window so the layout pops to vertical, when you resize back up the layout doesn't pop back

has anyone else found this and solved it?

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution here

[Flex items not shrinking when window gets smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382734/flex-items-not-shrinking-when-window-gets-smaller)

```
min-width: 0;
```

on the items :)

Answer (score 3):

That did not work for my linechart, I had to use :

```
canvas
{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

from https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/614