# CSS Scroll Bar Not Showing

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox

I've always had difficulty getting layout to work with `CSS`.  I'm sure there's something I'm missing.  Basically, I have a web page that consists of two columns side-by-side.  The column on the right contains a square with a fixed width of `200px`.  The column on the left should be expandable.  The content of the page, consisting of both columns together, should have a `max-width` of `400px`.  When the width of the screen is between `200px` and `400px`, the left column should shrink, but the right column should always be `200px`.

The problem is that there's some text in the left column consisting of a long word with no spaces.  This word happens to be a URL, but it could probably be anything, so long as it doesn't have any spaces.  It seems to prevent the left column from shrinking.  I tried adding a horizontal scrollbar for the region in the left column that contains the long word, but the scrollbar won't show up.

The two columns are `flexbox` items.  I'd prefer to keep them that way, or have them be `grid` items.  The only reason I'm using `flexbox` instead of grid is because I'm more familiar with `flexbox`.  I just didn't want to use floats for layout, since I thought that might get messy in the long run.

Could someone explain to me why the scrollbar does not show up when the width of the screen shrinks to between `200px` and `400px`?  If I could get the scrollbar to show up when the width of the screen shrinks, it would fix all of the layout difficulties:)

Here's the code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.center-wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.left-col {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.right-col {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
}

.urls {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.long-url {
  //display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center-wrapper">
    <div class="left-col">
      <h1>Some title</h1>
      <div>Some details</div>
      <div class="main-content">
      This is just some text.  Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
      
        <div class="urls">
          <ol class="list">
            <li>
              <span class="long-url">http://example.com/some/really/long/url#withasuperlonghashtag</span>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's another instance of the same problem, but without the long unbroken word:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.center-wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.left-col {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.right-col {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
}

.other-rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.urls {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.long-url {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center-wrapper">
    <div class="left-col">
      <h1>Some title</h1>
      <div>Some details</div>
      <div class="main-content">
        This is just some text. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.

        <div class="urls">
          <div class="other-rectangle"></div>
          <ol class="list">
            <li>
              <span class="long-url">http://example.com/some/really/long/url#withasuperlonghashtag</span>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would it fix if you set `word-break` to either `break-all` or `break-word`?

Comment: @lastr2d2:  Thanks, I wasn't aware of that as a workaround.  I'm still interested in knowing why the scrollbar doesn't display, but in the event that it's impossible to set, I'll definitely use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be happening because of the default `min-width: auto` property setting on the `.left-col` flexbox item.  This prevents the `.left-col` item from being smaller than its content.  When I use:

```
.left-col {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

for `.left-col`, the scrollbar appears.  I found out due Michael Benjamin's answer to another stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38383437/332988).

Answer (score 1):

Try set `word-break` to `break-all`.

```
.left-col {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

With the default value `normal`, line breaks in the text can only occur in certain spaces, like when there is a space or a hyphen. But when it comes to a long copy and pasted URL, if that URL has no hyphens, it can extend beyond the parent box and look bad or worse. A scrollbar won't be there because the browser doesn't know where to put the line break.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think something else might be causing the scrollbar to not appear.  When I set 'display: none;' for .long-url and create a new child div under the .urls div with `width:320px`, the scrollbar still doesn't appear.  I'm not sure why, though.  It just seems like no matter what I do with the child elements of the .urls div, `overflow-x: auto` has no effect:(

Comment: can you convert the code in the question to a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)?

Comment: I'll try:)  I've never done it before, but here goes:)

Comment: I changed all instances of `320px` to `200px` and `500px` to `400px`.  Otherwise, the original question is unchanged.  In my comment, I only meant to say that the issue I'm having with the layout doesn't seem to just be caused by the long unbroken word, although your answer does help.  It's just that if I uncomment `display: none` and then add a child div to `.urls` with `width: 200px; height: 200px; background: lightgreen;`, the left-column still doesn't want to shrink by creating a scrollbar for `.urls`....  I'll add another stack snippet:)

Answer (score -1):

**In case scrollbar is not shown up:**

***Add the code below to your css file:***
**You can also customize the way you like**

```
                ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                    width: .5rem;
                    height: 5px;
                }

                /* Track */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px white;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                }

                /* Handle */
                ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                    background: grey;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                }
```